# Не работают методы для работы с Whisper'ом

Tags: api

Перед началом работы был установлен geth с официального сайта. Запуск geth'а происходит со следующими параметрами

```
--shh --testnet --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,shh,personal"
```

Начинается синхронизация блоков в тестовой среде. До начала работы блоки уже были синхронизованы. После этого запускаю geth с параметром attach для работы с JavaScript-API. Команды беру со следующего [ресурса](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3shh). Проблема возникает, когда запускаю следующую команду:

```
var identity = web3.shh.newIdentity();
```

В ответ на что получаю, следующую ошибку:

```
Error: The method shh_newIdentity does not exist/is not available
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Проверял версию whisper'а, при проверке через JS API выдавалась 5 версия. По идее в этой версии данная функция должна работать и выдавать соответствующий id для дальнейшей работы. В каком моменте допустил ошибку и как можно исправить её? Возможно кто-то уже пытался начать работу через whisper, буду очень благодарен, если подскажете как получилось успешно отправить сообщение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка. Как раз для версии 5 данный метод уже не работает. [Whisper-Usage](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper-Usage), используется метод `shh.newKeyPair()`